# How to create a video streaming httpserver?

Tags: c++, http, poco

I'm using c++ and poco libraries. I'm trying to implement a video streaming httpserver.
Initially i used Poco::StreamCopier. 
But client failed to stream.
Instead client is downloading the video.
How can i make the server to send a streamresponse so that client can stream the video in browser instead of downloading?

Comment: I'm not sure that Poco::SreamCopier intended for streaming video content. Even if name gives you such assumptions. So you'd better to check FFMPEG library for RTP/MJPEG implementation.

Comment: Why don't you use Ngnix?

Comment: mpeg4ip is the project that you should be referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not within POCO, you could use ffmpeg. It has streaming servers for a number of video protocols and is written in C (which you could write POCO-like adapters for).

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#rtp

http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Protocols

http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=tree

And it has a pretty liberal license:
http://ffmpeg.org/legal.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to research which video encoding and container that is right for streaming -- not all video files can stream

Answer (score 0):

Without using something to decode the video at the other end but simply over HTTP, you can use The mime encoding "content-type:multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=..." and send a series of jpeg images.

This is actually called M-JPEG over HTTP.  See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG

The browser will replace each image as it receives it which makes it look like it's video.  It's probably the easiest way to stream video to a browser and many IP webcameras support this natively.

However, it's not bandwidth friendly by any means since it has to send a whole jpeg file for each frame.  So if you're going to be using this over the internet it'll work but will use more bandwidth than other method.

However, It is naively supported in most browsers now and it sounds like that is what you're after.